# VBScript: Need to set variable based on date created and string in filename

Tags: date, vbscript, wildcard

I am creating a SQL Server integration package that requires some VBScript.  Basically, every few days there is a file that is uploaded to a folder on my computer.  This file always has a different name, but it always contains the same string.

For example, the file for yesterday could have been "John J July 15.xlsx" and the file for tomorrow might be "John Jones Jul 17 2012.xlsx".  They all contain "John" and they always will.  I always want to set my variable to equal the filename of the file that contains "John" AND has a DateCreated attribute equal to today.

Is there something wrong with my code?  I can't get it to work.  Is the "Today.Date" also returning a time?  I only want it to return a date.  Does the Name attribute return the extension also?

```
    Public Sub Main()
    Dim f, fl, fs As Object
    Dim filedate As Date = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Today.Date
    Dim firstFileName As String

    fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fl = fs.GetFolder("E:\myFolder")

    For Each f In fl.Files
        If f.DateCreated = filedate And f.Name = "John*" Then
            firstFileName = f.Name
            Dts.Variables("ExcelSource").Value = "E:\myFolder\" & firstFileName
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the wildcard character in your IF statement above will work as you intend here. It will compare the filename with the *literal* "*" character, and match nothing. I might suggest something like:

****EDIT***: The DateCreated property does resolve to the second, so the comparison you have above won't work, either. Here's a very rough and untested illustration of one way you could modify to test for the proper date (omitting the seconds resolution).*

```
...
If Year(fileDate)=Year(f.DateCreated) and _
   Month(fileDate)=Month(f.DateCreated) and _ 
   Day(fileDate)= Year(f.DateCreated) and  _
   Left(f.Name,4)="John" Then
...
```

Comment: Take a look at the revision I just posted..might help. You might also have to amend the date comparison to the specific month and day, because I don't recall offhand if the file creation date property resolves down to the second. That would cause the other half of the if to fail as well...

Comment: Format the date to a date without the time:  Dim myDate  myDate = FormatDateTime(f.DateCreated, 2)

Comment: I used sorceri's advice and used your advice about using LEFT.  It works now!! Thanks guys!